# Converting String array to CGFloat array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Here is my String array:

```
let StringArray = ["1.4", "75.3", "23.4"]
```

And i wan't to convert this String Array to a CGFloat Array how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `map` to transform each element from one type to another type:

```
let doubleArray = StringArray.map {
    CGFloat(($0 as NSString).doubleValue)
}
```

The cast to `NSString` is needed because there's no string to double conversion in plain swift - at least I am not aware of any.